# WCS report TIFF not supported in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wps, ogc, wcs

I have a WPS running in GeoServer but the requests fails due to a exception:

The request to sum all values in a region:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:RasterZonalStatistics</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>data</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tif" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.0.0">
            <ows:Identifier>CSR:areas_of_endemism</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <gml:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                <ows:LowerCorner>-73.98318216 -33.75117799312799</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>-29.99993216 5.269572006872011</ows:UpperCorner>
              </gml:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tif"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>zones</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:CSR="csr.ufmg.br">
            <wfs:Query typeName="CSR:biome_amazon_am"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>classification</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tif" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.0.0">
            <ows:Identifier>CSR:bio_conserv_prior_arthropods_deforest_perc30</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <gml:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                <ows:LowerCorner>-75.45176103044321 -17.847385259953924</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>-42.415647949967656 6.646507267816007</ows:UpperCorner>
              </gml:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tif"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
      <ows:Identifier>statistics</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

And the expcetion is:

```
<wps:ExecuteResponse xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:x
link="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" service="WPS" serviceInstance="http://maps.csr.ufmg.br:80/geoserver/ows?" version="1.0.0">
    <wps:Process w
ps:processVersion="1.0.0">
        <ows:Identifier>ras:RasterZonalStatistics</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>Raster Zonal Statistics</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>Computes s
tatistics for the distribution of a certain quantity in a set of polygonal zones.</ows:Abstract>
    </wps:Process>
    <wps:Status creationTime="2019-06-07T00:20:4
0.652Z">
        <wps:ProcessFailed>
            <ows:ExceptionReport version="1.1.0">
                <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
                    <ows:ExceptionText>Process failed during e
xecution
Process execution d7a3c5ac-9a1d-443d-9919-37254a5a2a0b failed
Failed to retrieve value for input data
format image/tif is not supported for this coverage</ows:ExceptionText>
                </ows:Exception>
            </ows:ExceptionReport>
        </wps:ProcessFailed>
    </wps:Status>
</wps:Execut
eResponse>
```

Trying to find the problem, I tested requesting WCS map:

```
<GetCoverage version="1.0.0" service="WCS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wcs" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.0.0/getCoverage.xsd">
    <sourceCoverage>CSR:uso_da_terra_2013</sourceCoverage>
    <domainSubset>
        <spatialSubset>
            <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
                <gml:pos>-73.98318216 -33.75117799312799</gml:pos>
                <gml:pos>-29.99993216 5.269572006872011</gml:pos>
            </gml:Envelope>
            <gml:Grid dimension="2">
                <gml:limits>
                    <gml:GridEnvelope>
                        <gml:low>0 0</gml:low>
                        <gml:high>6736 5059</gml:high>
                    </gml:GridEnvelope>
                </gml:limits>
                <gml:axisName>x</gml:axisName>
                <gml:axisName>y</gml:axisName>
            </gml:Grid>
        </spatialSubset>
    </domainSubset>
    <output>
        <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
        <format>tif</format>
    </output>
</GetCoverage>
```

And I got almost the same error:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0" >
    <ServiceException code="InvalidParameterValue" locator="format">
      format tif is not supported for this coverage
    </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I am using GeoServer 2.15.1

I concluded that the issue is with the WCS, but I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I guess that the correct format is `image/tiff`. You can find the supported formats by making a GetCapabilities request for the WCS Service.

Comment: @user30184 no success, same error.

Comment: What formats did you see in GetCapabilities?

Comment: @user30184 i am not sure but: i have the following 'profiles': gml-coverage, special-format, geotiff-coverage, crs-gridded-coverage. I not sure, all these are each in a <ows:Profile> element.
PS: The 2.0 request had worked, but the 1.0.0 isnt, one uses coverageId the other use identifier wich is 'CSR:bio_conserv_prior_arthropods_deforest_perc30' . ' http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=CSR__bio_conserv_prior_arthropods_deforest_perc30&format=image/geotiff '

Comment: Sorry, i have found the supported formats: application/gml+xml, 
application/x-gzip, 
image/jpeg, 
image/png, 
image/tiff, 
text/plain

Comment: You should add your fix as an answer not as an edit to the question

Comment: I did it, below @nmtoken thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the WCS 2.0.1 request working

[Working WCS 2.0.1 Request](http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=CSR__bio_conserv_prior_arthropods_deforest_perc30&format=image/geotiff)

In XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 ../../wcsAll.xsd"
    service="WCS" version="2.0.0">
    <wcs:requestParameters>
        <wcs:mediatype>multipart/related</wcs:mediatype>
        <wcs:Format>image/geotiff</wcs:Format>
    </wcs:requestParameters>
    <wcs:CoverageId>CSR__uso_da_terra_2013</wcs:CoverageId>
</wcs:GetCoverage>
```

The request that finally worked for WPS, is using the (WCS 2.0) requests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:RasterZonalStatistics</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>data</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
            <wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                service="WCS" version="2.0.1">
                <wcs:requestParameters>
                    <wcs:mediatype>multipart/related</wcs:mediatype>
                    <wcs:Format>image/geotiff</wcs:Format>
                </wcs:requestParameters>
                <wcs:CoverageId>CSR__areas_of_endemism</wcs:CoverageId>
            </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>zones</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:CSR="csr.ufmg.br">
            <wfs:Query typeName="CSR:biome_amazon_am"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>classification</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
            <wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                service="WCS" version="2.0.1">
                <wcs:requestParameters>
                    <wcs:mediatype>multipart/related</wcs:mediatype>
                    <wcs:Format>image/geotiff</wcs:Format>
                </wcs:requestParameters>
                <wcs:CoverageId>CSR__bio_conserv_prior_arthropods_deforest_perc30</wcs:CoverageId>
            </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
      <ows:Identifier>statistics</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```